# Laravel ajax response issue returning with html content

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I am using ajax for ratings. Rating successfully but return response with html code above the json. And it is because of send mail function.
[image]
[image]

The  this code alwasy attached when return response and may be it was from send mail function.
When I am removing Mail function it will return proper result and its working well.

Comment: Post code, not screenshots

Comment: Here is my response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{"status":200,"msg":"Rate given successfully.","result":[]}

Answer (score 0):

If i were in your place i will work with jobs.
So Here is how it goes

```
php artisan make:job SendingEmail
```

App\Jobs\SendingEmail.php

```
 <?php
```

namespace App\Jobs;

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendingEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $admin_email;
protected $email_data;
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($admin_email,$email_data)
{
    $this->email_data = $email_data;
    $this->admin_email = $admin_email;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Mail::to($this->admins_email)->send(new RateNotification($this->email_data));
}
}
```

App\Jobs\SendingEmail::dispatch($podcast);

In Your Controller add this

```
App\Jobs\SendingEmail::dispatch($admin_email,$email_data);
```

Comment: My RateNotification code:
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view(
                'emails.admin.rate-notification',
                [
                    'rate' => $this->data['rate'],
                    'review'=>$this->data['review'],
                    'rate_for' => $this->data['for_user'],
                    'rate_from' => $this->data['from_user'],
                    'link' => $this->data['page_link'],
                    'notification_type' => 'Admin'
                ]
            )
            ->subject('A Rating Given @ VeloGuide.com');
    }

Comment: I ma not sending email in RateNotification class

Comment: Check i edit the response. is better to use jobs in this cases

Comment: @MohmedBenhida Same issue, I can't resolve using larave jobs